# Why does my IE progress bar keep going after every other page load?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, postback, progress-bar, http-compression

I'm seeing [this issue](http://www.activewidgets.com/javascript.forum.5142.2/ie-progress-bar-keeps-going.html).

I have a relatively simple ASP.NET page with a gridview and some buttons. When I click a button, the page re-binds the grid and posts back.

What's strange is that every other time I click the refresh button, the IE progress bar (in the status area) stays "on", signaling that the user that the page is still loading...forever.

I've reproduced this on other pages--it seems to occur every time a post-back occurs.

Confirmed in IE7 and IE8, but doesn't happen in FF3.5.

Any ideas?

---

**Update 1:**

This appears to happen only when the server is configured for HTTP Compression.

In either case (compressed or not), fiddler shows just a single request which is served successfully. But, when compression is enabled, I get the problematic behavior.

Comment: If you use Fiddler's "Remove all encodings" rules menu, do you see that the problem goes away?

Comment: @EricLaw -MSFT-: thanks for helping out--fiddler2 is an essential tool in my box. Thanks for showing me another great feature of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this in the past with various setups, and never sorted it out.  In one case I was able to use diagnostic logging on the server side to confirm that all http requests were complete.  I found a technique that worked in order to make the progress bar go away though it really made me cringe:   After a period of time (using setTimeout), write a 1x1 iframe to the bottom of the page, loading a blank html file.  Of course, this was using IE5 or IE6 or something (it was ages ago), so that may not work any longer.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. It's definitely not script related (I just posted an update) but your technique might help me here.